# How can i write this regex in such a way that it will capture an unknown amount of lines prefixed with?

Tags: regex, multiline

How would one go about matching all the following lines after a initial expression that has some sort of identifying feature?

For instance say you have the text:

```
The first line of text
! then another line of subtext
! then another....
! and so on..
The second line of text
! and so on..
```

What would be the correct approach to get a match where the following:

```
The first line of text
! then another line of subtext
! then another....
! and so on..
```

is the first match and

```
The second line of text
! and so on..
```

is the second match?

Would the following be a correct approach?

```
(.*)(\n!(?).*)*
```

Any insight and tips is appreciated!

Comment: You should add the regex101 link instead of just adding screenshot, it is ready to fiddle and will help you to get the solution earlier

Comment: Why not just add the global and multiline flags?

Answer (score 1):

With DOTALL option "on", match using a negative look ahead for the start of the next text block:

```
^[^!](.(?!^[^!]))*
```

eg in java:

```
"(?s)^[^!](.(?!^[^!]))*"
```

in perl:

```
/^[^!](.(?!^[^!]))*/s
```

in javascript (which doesn't support DOTALL flag):

```
/^[^!]([\s\S](?!^[^!]))*/
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/9B3hvIAuBF) (capturing group added to regex only for match display purposes)

Breakdown:

- `^[^!]` matches the start of line that isn't a `!`
- `(.(?!^[^!]))` matches any character (including newlines with DOTALL on) that are *not* followed by the start of a new text block

Comment: [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vP6vL8/1), I added a capturing group to show that this answer works great. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Using this: `The \w+ line of text((.|\n)(?!The \w+ line of text))+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL4uZ3/2))

Explanation:

```
The \w+ line of text // match the first line of the segment
(
    (.|\n) // match anything, including newlines
    (?!The \w+ line of text) // not followed by a segment's first line
)+ // match this one or more times
```